# NSFont Height For Drawing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-graphics, nsview, nsfont

When ever I set the pointSize for a NSFont the output text does not reach the exact height of point size, for instance when I set it to 20.0 the output text for a capital B is 17.0 pixels tall. Since I'm using it to draw text on a NSView it's causing some measuring problems for me.
Is there any accurate methods to measure the maximum height of text?

I'm drawing the strings with this method:
[stringValue drawInRect:stringRect withAttributes:stringAttributes];

Regards

Comment: Font sizes are in points, not pixels. A 17pt font is not 17 pixels tall.

Comment: Thank you for your response. How can convert them to pixels?

Comment: the formula is the simple: `pixel = point * dpi  / 72`, where the `dpi` is the current screen's `dpi`.

Comment: Not that simple because kerning and font variations are not taken into account.

Comment: Monitor DPIs are usually 72 so it will be automatically 17 pixels tall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Font Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/FontHandling/FontHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009459-CH5-SW18%20%22Querying%20font%20metrics) in the Cocoa documentation. Scroll down to 'Querying Font Metrics': this clearly shows how the different metrics such as descender, ascender and leading are used.